# sum one corresponding list element within python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of an arbitrary number of equal-length python dictionaries with matching sets of keys which are lists, like this:

```
[{'Item 1':[5.25, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[8.50, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[12.50, 'Tan', 'Medium']}, 
{'Item 1':[10.50, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[14.25, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[17.25, 'Tan', 'Medium']}, 
{'Item 1':[12.25, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[20.25, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[24.25, 'Tan', 'Medium']}]
```

The list of attributes for each product is the same, except for the first item, an int or float.

How can I obtain a single dictionary with the same set of keys and the same set of values, but the first item in the list is summed? In other words, I want to return:

```
{'Item 1':[28.00, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[43.00, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[54.00, 'Tan', 'Medium']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works if the input is as you state:

```
> lst = [
  {'Item 1':[5.25, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[8.50, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[12.50, 'Tan', 'Medium']}, 
  {'Item 1':[10.50, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[14.25, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[17.25, 'Tan', 'Medium']}, 
  {'Item 1':[12.25, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 2':[20.25, 'Blue', 'Small'], 'Item 3':[24.25, 'Tan', 'Medium']}
]

> {k: [sum(d[k][0] for d in lst)] + lst[0][k][1:] for k in lst[0]}
{
  'Item 3': [54.0, 'Tan', 'Medium'], 
  'Item 2': [43.0, 'Blue', 'Small'], 
  'Item 1': [28.0, 'Red', 'Large']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
result = {k: [sum(d[k][0] for d in price_list)] + v[1:] for k,v in price_list[0].items()}

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'Item 1': [28.0, 'Red', 'Large'], 'Item 3': [54.0, 'Tan', 'Medium'], 'Item 2': [43.0, 'Blue', 'Small']}
```